# Manipulating Zip archives with Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, rubygems, zip

I'm relatively new to Ruby, and I have to use the version 1.8.7.

I have tried 'zip' and ended up with a cryptic stack trace while attempting to use the example from the docs. My script

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'zip'
require 'zip/zipfilesystem'

Zip::ZipFile.open("myfile.war") do |a|
    puts a.file.read("META-INF/context.xml")
end
```

produces the following:

```
$./rzip.rb 
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/zip-2.0.2/lib/zip/zip.rb:1137:in `dup': can't dup NilClass (TypeError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/zip-2.0.2/lib/zip/zip.rb:1137:in `dup'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/zip-2.0.2/lib/zip/zip.rb:1137:in `map'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/zip-2.0.2/lib/zip/zip.rb:1137:in `dup'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/zip-2.0.2/lib/zip/zip.rb:1373:in `initialize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/zip-2.0.2/lib/zip/zip.rb:1384:in `new'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/zip-2.0.2/lib/zip/zip.rb:1384:in `open'
    from ./rzip.rb:7
```

What is wrong with my code? Or is it some version incompatibility issue? If it is not my blunder, what should I use for zip archives manipulations?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error [although it seems you are not alone in this](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/issues/82). Can I suggest using Zip::ZipFile. This is running on my system (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS):

```
require 'zip/zip'
Zip::ZipFile.open("my.zip", Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) {
 |zipfile|
  zipfile.get_output_stream("first.txt") { |f| f.puts "Hello from ZipFile" }
  zipfile.mkdir("a_dir")
}
```

You can also see [see some good examples/usage of Zip::ZipFile on GitHub](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/blob/master/samples/example.rb)

Comment: No, doesn't work for me, although we use the same OS. I have made a test zip file, using standard Linux zip utility, and _this_ worked by the book (both your way and mine). So apparently there are some cases this gem doesn't handle well. The file that causes trouble unpacks without problem using standard CLI tool (unzip).

Comment: @badbishop what error are you generating with my answer?

Comment: Same as in the original question.

Comment: I've narrowed the problem down a bit. I've unzipped the problematic file and then zipped the deflated files into another archive. Although both unzip to identical result, the output of unzip -l is different. Namely, some files are missing from the list in case of the trouble-causing file (which was generated by some Python script). The two zip files do also differ in size (about 10%).

Comment: @badbishop i'be thinking about your problem. have you ruled out file permisiioms? cd into the directory and run ls -al?

Comment: I think I may have found the cause. There is a directory in the archive with a dash as the first character in its name, and this is where the aforementioned difference in unzip -l happens. So, the archive was not cleanly generated with a Python script, and Zip::ZipFile doesn't handle such things, perhaps - unlike zip CLI utility.

Comment: @badbishop if can you record the steps to reproduce the error you should probably raise an issue with the developers?